# Bash how to get text in file

Tags: bash

1. I file /tmp/txt
2. contents of the file: aaa aaa aaa _bbb bbb bbb
3. I need to save the file /tmp/txt_left: **aaa aaa aaa**
4. I need to save the file /tmp/txt_right: **bbb bbb bbb**

!!! attention seeking solutions without the use of **variables** !!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) And why the "no variables" restriction? This sounds an awful lot like homework.

Comment: why *without the use of variables*? And what it mean? Could we modifying standard variables (like `$1` or `$IFS`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '_'  '{print $1> "/tmp/txt_left"; print $2 > "/tmp/txt_right" }' /tmp/txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try cutting the line, slitting on the underscore

```
Cat /tmp/txt | cut -d_ -f 1 > txt_left
```

Comment: Cat /tmp/txt | cut -d_ -f 0 > txt_left -> **cut: fields and positions are numbered from 1**

Comment: Useless use of `cat`! use `cut -d_ -f1 </tmp/txt >/tmp/txt_left` insetad!!

Comment: error cut: the delimiter must be a single character :-(

Answer (score 1):

#### A sed way:

Shorter and quicker:

```
sed -ne $'h;s/_.*$//;w /tmp/txt_left\n;g;s/^.*_//;w /tmp/txt_right' /tmp/txt
```

Explained: It could be written:

```
sed -ne '
    h;        # hold (copy current line in hold space)
    s/_.*$//; # replace from _ to end of line by nothing
    w /tmp/txt_left
              # Write current line to file
              # (filename have to be terminated by a newline)
    g;        # get (copy hold space to current line buffer)
    s/^.*_//; # replace from begin of line to _ by nothing
    w /tmp/txt_right
              # write
 ' /tmp/txt
```

#### Bash as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

This is not a real variable, I use first argument element for doing the job and restore argument list once finish:

```
set -- "$(</tmp/txt)" "$@"
echo >>/tmp/txt_right ${1#*_}
echo >>/tmp/txt_left ${1%_*}
shift
```

I *unshift* the string at first place in argument line,
do operation on `$1`, than `shift` the argument line so no variable is used and in fine, the argument line return in his original state

... and this is a **pure `bash`** solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash process substitution, tee, and cut:

```
tee -a >(cut -d _ -f 0 > /tmp/txt_left) >(cut -d _ -f 1 >/tmp/txt_right) < /tmp/txt
```